# Generating files based on Service.svcmap by command line tool

Tags: c#

Do you have any idea, how could be generated the derived files (***.xsd, *.wsdl, *.svcinfo, *.datasource** and finally **Reference.cs**) using the **Reference.svcmap** file? It's easy in VS (2015) by right-clicking and choosing *"Update Service Reference"*, but how does it work using any command line tool? (Without **Reference.cs** the solution cannot be compiled, generating the required files as a prebuild event would be nice.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you are looking for the svcutil.exe tool:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

**UPDATE:**

I've done some more digging. The custom tool used is defined in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.WCF, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` assembly. This does not seem to be used in the `svcutil.exe` tool. The assembly is located in the gac, but I don't know, how it can be executed using the command line. Your best bet is probably to get the wsdl for your service reference and use the svcutil tool instead.

Actually, I've just tried generating code using the Reference.svcmap file only, and the result was an empty Reference.cs file containing only the "autogenerated" comment. So, the Reference.svcmap file alone is not enough to generate the client proxy code. You will need more input than this. When you trigger the "update service reference" option in Visual Studio, it typically fetches all the metadata from the metadata exchange endpoint and regenerates your code. This can also be achieved using the `svcutil.exe` by passing in the service's url.

Comment: Thank you, but most probably **svcutil.exe** is not suitable to do this. It can use the ***.xsd, *.wsdl** files for generating the **Reference.cs**, but cannot do the first step (generating these file types from **Reference.svcmap**. Or maybe, but the correct parameter list for achieving it is unknown for me.